# Find the remainder of $5^{4321}$ upon division by 11

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find the remainder of $5^{4321}$ upon division by 11?

Comment: Which is it, $5^{4321}$ or $54321$?

Comment: 5^4321 is the correct one

Comment: Study Fermat;s theorem and use the tricks like:  $ a^{72}=(a^{12})^6$

Comment: also need to find a pattern

Comment: Be specific. What do you mean by 'find a pattern'.

Answer (score 4):

$5^{4321} \pmod{11} \equiv 5^{4321 \pmod {10}} \equiv 5^{1 \pmod{10}} \equiv 5 \pmod{11}$

The key thing to note here was that $\varphi(11) = 10$ because $11$ is prime. $\varphi$ of course is the Euler $\varphi$-function.